# foundation 5 sticky magellan vertical menu

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, sticky, magellan

I'm trying to reproduce a magellan sidebar menu like the one on this link http://jsfiddle.net/mBSA4/

```
<ul class="magellan tabs vertical" data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <li data-magellan-arrival="grid"><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
  <li data-magellan-arrival="tabs"><a href="#tabs">Tabs</a></li>
  <li data-magellan-arrival="buttons"><a href="#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
</ul>
```

But it's in foundation 4 and doesn't seem to work as expected with foundation 5.  I'm trying some things but I just can't reproduce a sticky vertical sidebar.  What I'm reproducing is a sidebar that goes full horizontal - on top of viewport - when I scroll.  Which is not the behavior I want.  I want a vertical ul-tab all the time.

Anybody had this resolved?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML code from Foundation 5 - and just replace the class "sub-nav" with "side-nav":

```
<dl class="sub-nav">
```

The code for my vertisidebar Magellan

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <dl class="side-nav">
    <dd data-magellan-arrival="tabs"><a href="#tabs">Tabs</a></dd>
    <dd data-magellan-arrival="code"><a href="#code">code</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps this is for an old version, but it doesn't work for me in Foundation 5.5. As soon as I start to scroll, the side-bar glues itself to the top and loses its right justification.